# How to clear authentication cookie when use it as subdomain domain cookie?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, authentication, cookies

In .Net Core using below code to make authentication cookie:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
  {
   options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
   options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
   options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
  .AddCookie(options =>
          {
              options.SlidingExpiration = false;
              options.LoginPath = "/Accounts/Login";
              options.LogoutPath = "/Accounts/Logout";
              options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Accounts/Forbidden/");
              options.Cookie.Name = "mycookie";
              options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
              options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
              
          });
```

and delete it in a controller:

```
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

it works OK but if use cookie like below:

```
options.Cookie.Domain = ".example.com";
```

it doesn't delete authentication cookie anymore.

Comment: Have checked if that can remove within same domain? Because you have defined as samesite cookie, so I am guessing, could you please check within the same domain if that works as expected?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron checked it, you have right it's because of "SameSiteMode.Strict;" If remove this line works as expected. but how to handle it with ?SameSiteMode"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, based on your scenario and description when you would use [CookieOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.cookieoptions?view=aspnetcore-7.0) property [SameSite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.cookieoptions?view=aspnetcore-7.0#properties) to `SameSiteMode.Strict` it would no longer track [cross-site cookie](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite?view=aspnetcore-7.0) in your case sub-domain cookie. Thus, in order to use cookie in cross-site or sub-domain you need to set [SameSiteMode.None](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite?view=aspnetcore-7.0#net-core-support-for-the-samesite-attribute) for `options.Cookie.SameSite`.

Please have a look below:

[image]

[image]

**Note:** [Please refer to this official document for details configuration on samesite cookie](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite?view=aspnetcore-7.0#net-core-support-for-the-samesite-attribute).